# vue js nested for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Есть массив ключей : `keyArr = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"]`
Есть хэштаблица : `myMap = {}`

```
myMap["key1"] = {field1 : "data", field2 : "data2"}
```

пишу:

```
 <tbody v-for="mKey in $root.keyArr">
      <tr v-for="item in $root.myMap[mKey]">
          <td>{{item.field1}}</td>
          <td>{{item.field2}}</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Как правильно вывести поля из обьеква ? Есть вариант   `<tr v-for="(value, key) in $root.myMap[mKey]">` но мне он не подходит.

Comment: чем не подходит-то?

Comment: Мне надо достать всёго 2 филда в обекте их много.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="key in keys">
    <li v-for="item in items[key]">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keys: ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"],
    items: {
      key1: {
        field1 : "data", 
        field2 : "data2"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Это тоже самое что на верху.

Comment: код работает, в чем, собственно, проблема?